# Why is my pie chart not displayed on my website?

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I'm building an Angular app that uses `Chart.js` to display various charts. I've created a standalone reusable component for the charts, and everything seems to work fine except for the pie chart. When I reload the page, the pie chart disappears and only shows up again when I navigate away and back to the page.

I've tried initializing the chart in both `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit`, and I've also tried removing all the properties from the component template to see if it would default to a bar chart, but the problem persists.

I'm using the latest version of `Chart.js` and its plugins, and I've checked the compatibility with my Angular version. I'm not sure what else to try at this point, and I'm wondering if anyone has experienced a similar issue or has any suggestions for a solution.

This is my standalone component:

```
import {
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  ViewChild,
  AfterViewInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Chart, ChartTypeRegistry, registerables } from 'chart.js';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

interface ChartData {
  labels: Array<string>;
  datasets: Array<DataSet>;
}
interface DataSet {
  label: string;
  data: Array<number>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chart.component.css'],
})
export class ChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  //Inputs
  @Input() public data: ChartData = {
    labels: ['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab', 'Dom'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: '# Postes levantados.',
        data: [25, 20, 30, 45, 50, 40],
      },
      {
        label: '# Postes fotografiados.',
        data: [15, 10, 20, 55, 11, 40],
      },
    ],
  };

  @Input() public type: string = 'bar';

  //chart from template
  @ViewChild('myCanvas')
  public myCanvas!: ElementRef;
  public ctx: any;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.ctx = this.myCanvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
    Chart.register(...registerables);
    this.loadChart();
  }

  loadChart(): void {
    new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: this.type as keyof ChartTypeRegistry,
      data: this.data,
      options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
      },

      plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    });
  }
}
```

This is my parent component in `home.component.ts` where I initialize my `data` to pass it via props with an input to my child component:

```
//Chart data
public chartData = {
  labels: ['Postes con tendido', 'Postes sin tendido'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'no labels',
      data: [50, 50],
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML code for `ChartComponent`? And also will be great if you can create a minimal, reproducible example in StackBlitz. I have tried to create [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwf6ba?file=src/main.ts) but cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hello thanks for taking the time for helping me, actually i solve this issue it was an css conflict so its ok right now, thanks, im gonna close this!.